# Android Authentication - What is the standard?

Tags: android, authentication

I am getting into Android development for the first time and am having a blast, of course.  I do have a question, though, about the general approach to authentication (for dealing with a backend).

To begin, here is, in a nut shell, what I have worked out.

Using google's documentation ([link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating)), I authenticate the user using the google sign in api.  I have put the logic mentioned in the reference in my app's main activity.  After the onConnected method fires, I have a successfully connected GoogleApiClient.

With the now connected GoogleApiClient, I use a call to GoogleAuthUtil.getToken to get an oath2 token that I use to authenticate requests to my backend.  Basically, any time I make an HTTP request to my backend, I include this token as a header.  My backend reads this token and uses the Python API google provides for verifying this token.  In the backend, I use the email that is embedded in the (now parsed) token to make sure the user to whom that oauth2 token was issued is, in fact, a user of my system.

Now, here are the questions.  First, does this sound like a reasonable approach to authentication on the Android platform?  What might I be missing?  What could go wrong?

The second question is a bit more direct.  When I get the oauth2 token from the client app, I store it and use the same token each time an HTTP request to a secured resource is made.  Eventually, of course, the token will expire.  From some limited testing using the Android emulator, it seems that if I shut down the application and restart it, I am getting the same, expired token back using the GoogleAuthUtil.getToken, rather than getting a fresh token with a new expiration in the future.  In my tests, I have had to restart the emulator in order to get a token with a correct expiry.  Am I mistaken here?  Is there something special I need to do to tell the Google API to issue me a new token?  Do I need to disconnect the GoogleApiClient and reconnect it?  I hope to avoid doing this in order to limit the number of activities that need to carry the callbacks required to complete this process.

Any words of wisdom here will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

after you have got your token you can use [Validate Token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#validatetoken), and if it responses with an error: 'invalid_token', you can use [GoogleAuth.clearToken(Context context, String token)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#clearToken(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) to clear the token and get a new token with the method you are using to get auth token.